# How to count the number of times a random number between '0-6' prints in a given array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to count the number of times a number from 0-6 appears in a given array that has values generated from a random number generator. However, my code just returns '0' instead of counting the number of times the number appears in the array. I am new to this, can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[7];
    int i;
    int zero=0;
    int one=0;
    int two=0;
    int three=0;
    int four=0;
    int five=0;
    int six=0;

    for (i=0; i<=7; i++)
            array[i] = i;

    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
    for (i=0; i<=7; i++)
    {
            int index1 = i;
            int index2 = rand()%7;

            int temp;
            temp = array[index1];
            array[index1] = array[index2];
            array[index2] = temp;



    if(i==48){zero++;}

     else{if(i==49){one++;}

    else{if(i==50){two++;}

     else{if(i==51){three++;}

     else{if(i==52){four++;}

    else{if(i==53){five++;}

    else{if(i==54){six++;}

     }}}}}}}

    for (i=0; i<=7; i++){
    printf("array[%d] = %d\n",i,array[i]);}
    printf("Number of times each number came up is:\n");
    printf("Zero:%d\n", zero);
    printf("One:%d\n", one);
    printf("Two:%d\n", two);
    printf("Three:%d\n", three);
    printf("Four:%d\n", four);
    printf("Five:%d\n", five);
    printf("Six:%d\n", six);




    return(0);
     }
```

Comment: 0)`i<=7` should be `i<7` 1) `i==48` always false because `for (i=0; i<=7; i++)`

Comment: regarding this kind of line: 'else{if(i==54){six++;}'  there is no need for the '{' between the else and the if, a space will do, then most of the string of trailing '}'s can be eliminated.   Please, for readability/clarity, indent (say 4 spaces) after each opening brace '{' and unindent (the same amount) before each closing brace '}'  Be sure to not use tabs for indenting as different editors/word processors often have different tab settings which makes the code nearly unreadable in different environments.  I.E. use spaces for indenting

Comment: there is a missing closing brace after the group of prints statements

Comment: the string of if/else statements would be much better written as a switch statement with case statements

Comment: the code block beginning with 'for (i=0; i<=7; i++)' (which should be: 'for(i=0; i<7; i++)' ) is missing the final closing brace '}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_RAND_NUMBERS (1000)

int main(void)
{

    int i;
    int randValue = 0;
    int array[7] = {0}; // initialize array counters to 0

    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) ); // initialize rand() function

    for (i=0; i<MAX_RAND_NUMBERS; i++)
    {
         randValue = rand()%7;

         array[randValue]++;
    } // end for 


    printf("total number of random numbers (limited range: 0...6): %d\n", MAX_RAND_NUMBERS );
    printf("Number of times each of the limited range numbers occurred is:\n");
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        printf("number: %d, occurrence count: %d\n",i,array[i]);
    }    


    return(0);
} // end function: main
```

Comment: I wrote this answer using 0..6 inclusive rather than between 0 and 6

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as mentioned above in a comment your statement :

for (i=0; i<=7; i++)

It has a error because in reality, it starts from 0 and goes all the way to 7, INCLUDING 7. That means you actually have 8 positions ( 0 -> 7) instead of (0 -> 6), which is what you desire to achieve. So it should be:

for (i=0; i < 7; i++)

That is not however the major problem. You said in your question :

> I am trying to count the number of times a number from 0-6 appears in a given array that has values generated from a random number generator

In the following code :

```
for (i=0; i< 7; i++)
        array[i] = i;`
```

Your array elements will not be random numbers because you assign them very determined numbers. More specifically, your array will be something like this: 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

To assign random numbers to an array I would do something like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
for(i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    array[i] = rand()%7; // this will generate numbers in the range of [0,6]
}
```

Ok, now you have an array of random numbers just as you wanted. So let's try to count them. I would try to implement an apparition array:

```
int apparition[7] = {0}; // this statement will initialize all values to 0
for(i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
   apparition[array[i]]++;
}
```

The code above does the following thing: it iterates over the array of numbers, and for each value it increments that specific apparition array element. Suppose you have array[i] = 6, then apparition[6] = 1, so you have counted one apparition.

Your code :

```
    if(i==48){zero++;}

 else{if(i==49){one++;}

else{if(i==50){two++;}

 else{if(i==51){three++;}

 else{if(i==52){four++;}

else{if(i==53){five++;}

else{if(i==54){six++;}
```

I suppose that you considered 48 to be the ASCII representation for 0, right?
That is not correct, because the 0 you see in that table is '0' which is actually a char value, not an integer value.
Instead you should have done

```
if(array[i] == 0) {zero++};
```

If you choose to implement the apparition array, you can print it like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; ++) {
    printf("%d appears: %d times\n", i, apparition[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps :-)